# cannot use angular js ng-app directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through the angular tutorial and it asked me to do the following:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="appname">
```

And then in my `app.js`:

```
app = angular.module('appname',[]);
```

I'm loading all of the angular files, including the `angular-route.min.js`.

Can someone please explain what I am doing incorrectly? The error I am receiving and cannot find a solution to is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

UPDATE:

Here is my `app.js`

```
    var spinner,app;
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        spinner = new Spinner();
        bindSearch();   
        $(".phonenumber").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999",{placeholder:" "});
        $(".zipcode").mask("99999?-9999",{placeholder:" "});    
        if(useDataTable){
            $("#loadingdiv").after(spinner.spin().el);
            reloadSearchItems();
        }   
        app = angular.module('appname',[]);
    });
```

Here is my html:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="appname" ng-strict-di>
```

Comment: please post some code..or a jsfiddle of ur code

Comment: there isn't anything in your question that needs `angular-route.min.js`, but you do need `angular.js` (or min) and you need your `app.js`.  we need to see more code to see what you might have incorrect.

Comment: your sequence should be angular.js then angular-route.js then app.js

Comment: hmm you posted an app.js that has a bunch of jquery in it, including the assignment of your angular module which is inside a `$(document).ready`.  So at the time angular initializes, your app isn't assigned yet, and can't be injected.

Comment: plus you are using `ng-strict-di`, which will fail to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation.  If any of your controllers are not defined properly, they would fail injection as well (unknown, as you haven't listed any HTML with controllers, or a controller class).

Comment: I know you may be beginning but try not to use jquery with angular. Angular doesn't need to use the $ DOM selection to do data work and it can cause more headaches than it's worth.